# Understanding memory behavior of Dask distributed

Tags: python, dask, dask-delayed

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38539044/1804173), I'm running into memory issues with Dask distributed. However, in my case the explanation is not that the client is trying to collect a large amount of data.

The problem can be illustrated based on a very simple task graph: A list of `delayed` operations generate some random DataFrames of a fixed size of ~500 MB (to simulate loading many partitions from files). The next operation in the task graph is to take the size of each DataFrame. Finally all sizes are reduced into one total size, i.e., the data that has to be returned to the client is small.

For testing purposes, I'm running a local scheduler/worker single-threaded, limited to 2GB memory, i.e.:

```
$ dask-scheduler
$ dask-worker localhost:8786 --nthreads 1 --memory-limit 2000000000
```

My expectation from the task graph is that the worker should never need much more than 500 MB of RAM, because running *"get data size"* directly after *"generate data"* should make the data small immediately. However, I'm observing that the worker needs much more memory than that:

[image: Memory usage]

The factor of 2 indicates that the data has to be duplicated internally. Therefore any attempts to bring the partition size close to the physical memory of a node results in `MemoryErrors` or heavy swapping.

Any information to shed some light on this is highly appreciated. In particular:

- Do I have any control over the duplication of the data, and is it something that can be avoided? Or is the general rule of thumb to keep the payload well below 50% to account for the data duplication?
- How does the worker `memory-limit` affect this behavior? From my tests, using a lower threshold seems to trigger GC earlier (and/or spill-to-disk?), but on the other hand there are other memory peaks which even exceed the peak memory of using a higher threshold.

Note that I'm aware that I could solve this particular issue by taking the size *within* the first operation, and probably Dask's single machine executor is better suited for the problem, but I'm asking for educational purposes.

---

**Attachment 1:** Test code

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from dask import delayed
from dask.distributed import Client, Executor


def simulate_df_partition_load(part_id):
    """
    Creates a random DataFrame of ~500 MB
    """
    num_rows = 5000000
    num_cols = 13

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in xrange(num_cols):
        data_col = np.random.uniform(0, 1, num_rows)
        df["col_{}".format(i)] = data_col
        del data_col    # for max GC-friendliness

    print("[Partition {}] #rows: {}, #cols: {}, memory: {} MB".format(
        part_id, df.shape[0], df.shape[1],
        df.memory_usage().sum() / (2 ** 20)
    ))
    return df


e = Executor('127.0.0.1:8786', set_as_default=True)

num_partitions = 2

lazy_dataframes = [
    delayed(simulate_df_partition_load)(part_id)
    for part_id in xrange(num_partitions)
]

length_partitions = [df.shape[0] for df in lazy_dataframes]
dag = delayed(sum)(length_partitions)

length_total = dag.compute()
```

---

**Attachment 2:** DAG illustration

[image: DAG]

Comment: How did you get the graph showing the memory? Plus is the graph per worker or all workers?

Comment: @AmyChodorowski This was just from the Dask monitoring dashboard, and I think it was referring to one worker only. Note that this question is a few years old, and perhaps the Dask monitoring dashboard has changed a little bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few questions here:

1. Why am I seeing twice as much memory use as a single data element?
2. Is recommended behavior to keep partition size well below total memory?
3. What happens when I extend beyond the --memory-limit value

#### Why am I seeing twice as much memory use?

The worker is likely running two create-data tasks before it gets to the first compute-size task.  This is because the scheduler assigns all currently-runnable tasks to workers, possibly more than they can run at once.  The worker completes the first one and reports back to the scheduler.  While the scheduler determines what new task to send to the worker (the compute-size task) the worker starts up another create-data task immediately.

#### Is recommended behavior to keep partition size well below total memory?

Yes.

#### What happens when I extend beyond the --memory-limit value?

The worker will start to write the least recently used data elements to disk.  It does this when you're at about 60% memory use by default (as measured by the `__sizeof__` protocol).

*Note: thank you for the well posed question*

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes it really clear. I added some logging to the generator + mapper, and I can confirm that this is exactly the behavior I'm getting: The first two tasks are generator tasks, and from there, mapper and generator tasks are alternating when using more than two partitions.